# google/microsoft/etc auth from x.com domain to use in other domain (like y.x.com or even clientDomain.com)

Tags: azure, authentication, google-oauth, token, azure-authentication

We have an app that let our users use their own domain to access our platform.

For example, if our website domain is "abc.com", we allow our user to use their own domain (for example "external.net") by setting this domain to point to our server.

To achieve it, we need to set their domain each time in our "Google Console"(/Microsoft) so that the authentication (we do have a login of course) will work with their domain as well...
[image]

The thing is that we think maybe we could accomplish such a result by just forcing all our users to use our main domain (abc.com) and just after they log in, we will redirect them to their domain.

It will save us the time to add each time their domain to "Google Console"(/Microsoft).
The question is if it's something that we really can do, or google will disallow such auth if which user comes from A domain, and will use B domain with the token he got from A domain.

*If such a thing is not allowed, is it allowed by using my subdomains? like user1.abc.com / user2.abc.com etc... without having to fill those subdomains in the provider console (Google/Microsoft).

I hope the question is clear enough,
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of app is this?
Why would they want to use their own domain your app should be hosted on your domain.

Answer (score 0):

A note about verification of your applicaiton.

In order to have this application verified you are going to to [Verify your site ownership](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9008080?hl=en) for every domain listed as a redirect Uri or a JavaScript origin.

So the only way that is going to work is if you can prove you own those domains.  By registering them in google search console.